# "Signed resources have been added, removed, or modified" when running iOS app on device

Tags: ios, code-signing, ios-app-extension

I have an app with an extension. Install and run works fine in the simulator, but after running my app from Xcode to the device once, on subsequent runs I get the following lines in the device log:

`Feb 22 16:10:02 Sams-iPad streaming_zip_conduit[7544] <Warning>: __dispatch_source_read_socket_block_invoke:203: Failed to install application at file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/Pinner.app_sparse.ipa/ : Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x13f5302a0 {Error=ApplicationVerificationFailed, ErrorDetail=-402620393, ErrorDescription=Failed to verify code signature of <MIPluginKitPluginBundle : path = /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.nhMRWT/extracted/Payload/Pinner.app/PlugIns/AddBookmarkExtension.appex identifier = com.blork.Pinner.AddBookmarkExtension type = 7> : 0xe8008017 (Signed resources have been added, removed, or modified)}`

Here's my code signing setup for the app:
[image: App]

And for the extension:
[image: Extension]

After cleaning the build folder, the app will then install again. This happens on two separate devices (iPad, iPhone).

I am using CocoaPods - I've tried removing them and setting up the project again, no luck there.

Comment: Does the problem persist when manually selecting the provisioning profiles and code signing identities?

Comment: @Dan That works the first time, then I get the error again. Interestingly that time I got an actual pop-up in Xcode rather than having to open the device log.

Comment: @blork Did you ever end up resolving this? I am getting similar errors.